# my bootstrap cards are hiding under side bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, styling, bootstrap-cards

i have added the bootstrap cards(in the image below) everything is working fine. but the problem is when i add a side bar and nav bar(actually another file,i included it with php). cards which are left side of the screen gets hidden under side bar.
if i write the following css ,then it takes 200px margin for every card.
what i want is only cards which are on the left side needs to be move towards left and the gap between each card must remain same.
i also tried frames but not working.

```
.cards{
         margin-left:200px;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: can you create a snippet to look into?

Comment: My snippet involves PHP but stack overflow is not accepting php

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how your html looks like, but lets assume it is like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <aside> ... menu </aside>
  <main> ... cards </main>
<div>
```

You can write css like this:

```
.content { display: flex }
aside { width: 200px }
main { width: calc(100% - 200px) }
```

I hope i understood the question.